# What is the difference between typedef and Macros?

Tags: c++, macros, typedef, ctime

What is the difference between `typedef` and Macros? We can just simply define a macro instead of using a typedef, and what does this Macro evaluate to `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (defined in `<ctime>`)?

Comment: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is supposed to be a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro is a text substitution performed by the preprocessor before compilation begins.

A `typedef` can be thought of as a synonym.

The macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC looks like it is an identifier that evaluates to some number for compilation.

On some platforms, CLOCKS_PER_SECOND is the number of *clock ticks* per second or the number of clock cycles per second.  It is a measure of time or performance.